# Show that every bipartite graph is a comparability graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that every bipartite graph is a comparability graph. A graph $G$ is a comparability graph if $G$ has a trasitive orientation $D$.

Well I'm a little confuse because I remember taht bipartite graphs can't have cycles of odd length and transitivity implies that we got a cycle of length $3$. I think I´m missing something here. Any hints?

Comment: I think your issues are with the (false) converse: "Every comparability graph is bipartite". But, your observation is very revealing nonetheless. Certainly if you have vertices $a, b, c$ connected like so $a \to b \to c$, then we get a triangle $a \to c$. So, if you orient your graph, you'll have to have every vertex be either a source or a sink.

Comment: Your bipartite graph has disjoint vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that every edge joins a vertex in $V_1$ to a vertex in $V_2$. If each edge is directed from the endpoint in $V_1$ to the endpoint in $V_2$, is not that a transitive orientation???

Comment: @user759562 can you put that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just to formalize what was stated in the comments, this is completely obvious from the definitions: Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $(X, Y)$. Recall that a graph is comparability if and only if it is transitively orientable; in simpler terms, this says that whenever we have a directed (not necessarily induced) $P_3$ (say $a \rightarrow b \rightarrow c$), we have $ac \in E(G)$, and moreover $a \rightarrow c$. For each $xy \in E(G)$ (where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$), orient this edge as $x \rightarrow y$. This chosen orientation obviously does not have a directed $P_3$ ($X$ and $Y$ are both independent, and there are no edges from $Y$ to $X$ by choice), and hence is vacuously transitive by our above characterization. Since $G$ was arbitrary, this gives that any bipartite graph is comparability, as desired.